# How to produce an array with values in a specific shape?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to create an array with values that range from 0.0 to 1.0 as shown here:
[weighting matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2yBN.png)

Basically, the left and top edges should remain close to 1.0 but slowly decay to 0.5 in the corners.
The bottom and right edges should remain close to 0.0
The middle region should be mostly 0.5, and the values should be decaying diagonally from 1.0 to 0.0.

This is what I've tried but it doesn't give me exactly what I would like.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x):
  y = np.zeros(len(x))
  for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x[i]))
  return y

sigmoid_ = sigmoid(np.linspace(20, 2.5, 30))
temp1 = np.repeat(sigmoid_.reshape((1,len(sigmoid_))), repeats=10, axis=0)
sigmoid_ = sigmoid(np.linspace(6, 3, 10))
temp2 = np.repeat(sigmoid_.reshape((len(sigmoid_),1)), repeats=30, axis=1)
alpha1 = temp1 + temp2

sigmoid_ = sigmoid(np.linspace(-2.5, -20, 30))
temp1 = np.repeat(sigmoid_.reshape((1,len(sigmoid_))), repeats=10, axis=0)
sigmoid_ = sigmoid(np.linspace(-3, -6, 10))
temp2 = np.repeat(sigmoid_.reshape((len(sigmoid_),1)), repeats=30, axis=1)
alpha2 = temp1 + temp2

alpha = alpha1 + alpha2
alpha = alpha - np.min(alpha)
alpha = alpha / np.max(alpha)

plt.matshow(alpha)
```

Which gives me this: [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGOWL.png)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is there a mathematical representation of what you want?  Because there are many ways to get something vaguely 2D sigmoidal.

Comment: @user633611 difference between rapidly and slowly?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest function I can think of:

```
tune_me = 101    
x = np.linspace(0, 1, tune_me)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, tune_me)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
sig = 1/(1 + np.exp(tune_me - xv - yv))

plt.matshow(sig)
```

But if you want something specific, you should probably figure out your math (maybe on the math stack exchange) before you try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the same function for all parts of the weighting matrix area, if not otherwise required. A sigmoid function (which changes rapidly near the center and slowly away from it) is indeed suitable after appropriate translation and scaling. For the sigmoid function's argument I'd choose the [taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) from a corner of the area.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = np.ndarray((10, 30))
ymax, xmax = alpha.shape[0]-1, alpha.shape[1]-1
for y in range(alpha.shape[0]):
    for x in range(alpha.shape[1]):
        M = x/xmax+y/ymax   # Manhattan distance, range [0;2]
        M -= 1              # make range [-1;1], so that inflection point is in the middle
        M *= 3.0            # the higher this factor, the steeper the sigmoid curve at the flex
        s = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-M))  # sigmoid function, range ]0;1[
        alpha[y, x] = 1-s   # decay from 1 to 0

plt.matshow(alpha)
plt.show()
# show the values close to 0.5
h = [(y, x) for y in range(alpha.shape[0])
            for x in range(alpha.shape[1]) if .4 < alpha[y, x] and alpha[y, x] < .6]
hy, hx = zip(*h)
plt.plot(hx, hy, 'o')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

#### Illustration of values in center region close to 0.5, e. g. in ]0.4;0.6[:[image]